# Need to run a privalaged program at startup without prompts but as local user

Tags: permissions, sudo, startup

I'm trying to launch a program at startup that requires sudo but as the local user that's logging in.

I have visudo edited to add:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
MY_USER ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/MY_PROGRAM             <-- added this line
```

The problem is that if I just add `/usr/bin/MY_PROGRAM` to startup (the Ubuntu Startup Applications GUI), it just prompts for a password and login keyring anyway & if I add sudo so `sudo /usr/bin/MY_PROGRAM` is launched at startup, it uses some other user configuration (probably root?) and is screwy/non-functional.

How can I launch this program as the local user but with sudo privilege automatically at startup? It's a VPN program if that makes any difference.

Comment: The question is unclear. If the program prompts for a password, it must have been launched, and you don't need to launch it again. Perhaps what you really mean is a file with VPN credentials, but that is for you to clarify.

Comment: The VPN application has a GUI which I am trying to run on startup without requiring a password.

Comment: Is this possible?